# How can I create left shifted discrete time signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, indices

```
 x[n]=n if 0<= n <=10 else x[n]=0;
```

I am able to plot x[n+3] and x[n-3] using stem. but I need to sum these two signals.During my trials I can t overcome the problem of negative indices.Is there anyway to do
   `y[n]= x[n+3]+x[n-3]` ?

In similar topics only right shift which is not causing negative indices has been answered.

Comment: so what is the problem in calculating x[n+3] and x[n-3]?

Comment: The syntax suggests you are using only arrays. Define a function for x and for y, this removes the problems with negatives indices.

Comment: @Parag problem is I can t type x[n-3] since n can not be negative.

Comment: @DanielR thank you I solved.can you add it answer so that others may use in future

Comment: You also had an `else` condition. That basically took the care of everything

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB requires you to have each logic case stored uniquely. The way you'd write it is probably:

```
if (0 <= n) && (n <= 10)
    x(n) = n;
else
    x(n) = 0;
end
```

Combining it into one longer expression:

```
if (0 <= n 0 <= 10)
```

Wouldn't work, and would always return true.

Comment: It is not a code itself.I just wrote it in code bracket in order to highlight it. I did noy try to type it if( 0 < n <10 ) in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : 
creating appropriate functions instead of arrays.

```
function O=Y(n)
if n<-3 && n>13
    O=0;
else
    O=X(n-3)+X(n+3);
end
```

And

```
function O=X(n)
 if n>=0 && n<=10
     O=n;
 else
     O=0;
 end;
```